# How can I validate a string in this format: p[1 or more numbers]?

Tags: php, regex, string

I want validate these form of strings:

```
$string = 'p123455...
```

- valid: p1, p22, p54342534535
- invalid: p, pp45, p543p, 4p5232, q34

(First character must be 'p' and the others 1 or more numbers)

My attempt:

```
$valid = true;

if($string[0] != 'p')
    $valid = false;

$string = substr($string, 1);

if(!is_numeric($string)
    $valid = flase;

if($valid)
    echo 'string is valid.';
```

But is there a shorter and faster way?

Comment: I guess the missing `)` in the second if statement is just a typo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a simple regex with [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to do your validation in one go:

```
if(preg_match("/^p\d+$/", $string)){
    //valid
} else {
    //not valid
}
```

Regex explanation:

- **^** anchor for the start of a string
- **p** literal p
- **\d** matches all digits (`0-9`)

  - **+** quantifier: matches 1 or more times
- **$** anchor for the end of a string

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_match()

```
$string = "p12345678";
if(preg_match('/^p[0-9]+$/',$string)) {
  echo "Valid";
} else {
  echo "Invalid";
}
```